# Bash: replace specific text with its translation

Tags: bash, file, translation

There is a huge file, in it I want to replace all the text between '=' and '\n' with its translation, here is an example:

```
input:

screen.LIGHT_COLOR=Lighting Color 
screen.LIGHT_M=Light (Morning)
screen.AMBIENT_M=Ambient (Morning)

output:

screen.LIGHT_COLOR=Цвет Освещения
screen.LIGHT_M=Свет (Утро)
screen.AMBIENT_M=Эмбиент (Утро)
```

All I have managed to do until now is to extract and translate the targeted text.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
        echo $line | cut -d= -f2- | trans -b en:ru

done < file.txt

output:
    Цвет Освещения
    Свет (Утро)
    Эмбиент (Утро)
```

**trans is short for translate-shell. It is slow, but does the job. -b for brief translation; en:ru means English to Russian.*

If you have any suggestions or solutions i'll be glad to know, thanks!

### edit, in case someone needs it:

After discovering trans-shell limitations I ended up going with the *@TaylorG.* suggestion. It is seams that translation-shell allows around 110 request per some time. Processing each line seperatly results in 1300 requests, which breaks the script.

***long story short***, it is faster to pack all the data into a single request. Its possible to reduce processing time from couple of minutes to mere seconds. sorry for the messy code, it's my third day with:

```
cut -s -d = -f 1 en_US.lang > option_en.txt
cut -s -d = -f 2 en_US.lang > value_en.txt

# merge lines
sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n/ :: /g' value_en.txt > value_en_block.txt

trans -b en:ru -i value_en_block.txt -o value_ru_block.txt

sed 's/ :: /\n/g' value_ru_block.txt > value_ru.txt

paste -d = option_en.txt value_ru.txt > ru_RU.lang

# remove trmporary files
rm option_en.txt value_en.txt value_en_block.txt value_ru.txt value_ru_block.txt
```

Thanks Taylor G., Armali and every commentator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pipe in a large loop is expensive. You can try the following instead.

```
cut -s -d = -f 1 file.txt > name.txt
cut -s -d = -f 2- file.txt | trans -b en:ru > translate.txt
paste -d = name.txt translate.txt
```

It shall be much faster than your current script. I'm not sure how your `trans` method is written. It needs to be updated to process batch input if it's not, e.g. using a while loop.

```
trans() {
    while read -r line; do
        # do translate and print result
    done
}
```

Comment: I believe their `trans` comes from https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell

Comment: your script may fail if there are any lines that don't have `=`

Comment: Thanks @jhnc for pointing that out. I added `-s` flag to `cut` to suppress lines without `=`.

Comment: @TaylorG.: Or with your idea and `bash`: `paste -d '=' <(cut -s -d = -f 1 file.txt) <(cut -s -d = -f 2- file.txt | trans -b en:ru)`

Answer (score 1):

You already did most of the work, though it can be optimized a bit. What's missing is just to output the first part of the line up to the equal sign together with the translation:

```
while IFS== read left right
do  echo $left=`trans -b en:ru <<<$right`
done <file.txt
```

Comment: maybe safer to quote the argument: `echo "..."`

Comment: Maybe, but I prefer to quote only if I see the need, otherwise I would never learn when I really have to quote. I the case at hand, the `echo` argument part to the right of `=` obviously needs no further quoting; the `$left` might need it, but it's kind of an identifier which I think can't contain special characters.